# How to delete a row if there is no value in a column?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete rows in table if there is no value in a certain column.

I've used a code that deletes rows if there is one cell value missing, but I would like to delete rows if a cell does not contain a value in a certain column.

For example, if there is no value in Column G Row 5 then I want to delete the entire row.

```
Sub Test2()

  Dim rng As Range
  On Error Resume Next
  Set rng = Range("Table3").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  End If

End Sub
```

This deletes all rows with any type of missing cell value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two small changes:

```
Sub Test2()

    Dim rng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Range("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        rng.EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to work directly with the table, then consider iterating over the `ListRows` of the table in question, something like this:

```
Sub Test2()
    Dim myTbl As ListObject
    Set myTbl = Sheet1.ListObjects("table3") ' change sheet as necessary

    Dim indx As Long
    indx = myTbl.ListColumns("ColumnName").Index

    Dim rngToDelete As Range

    Dim myRw As ListRow
    For Each myRw In myTbl.ListRows
        If IsEmpty(myRw.Range(1, indx).Value) Then
            If rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDelete = myRw.Range
            Else
                Set rngToDelete = Union(rngToDelete, myRw.Range)
            End If
        End If
    Next myRw

    If Not rngToDelete Is Nothing Then
        rngToDelete.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
    End If
End Sub
```

Note: Technically, it's `xlShiftUp`, not `xlUp`.

Comment: Tried to run this code but I got: Run-time error '1004'

Comment: Do you have an actual table (`ListObject`), or are you dealing with a range named "table3"?

Comment: There is an actual table "Table 3"

Comment: Then change `Range("G:G")` to something like `myTbl.ListColumns("columnname").DataBodyRange`, where `myTbl` is the `ListObject`.

Comment: @icalderon in certain circumstances, deleting an entire row will fail if a `ListObject` is involved - consider iterating the `ListRows` instead, and invoking `ListRow.Delete` to delete the *table row* (not the entire *worksheet row*).

Comment: Yep @MathieuGuindon I suspect this may be the case here.

Comment: Thank you BigBen and @MathieuGuindon. I'm still fairly new to vba, how can I got about doing what you suggested?

Comment: I changed the sheet name to _Kit_db_ where the table is located but a 'Run-time error '424'' pops up. 

`Dim myTbl As ListObject
    Set myTbl = Kit_db.ListObjects("Table3") ' change sheet as necessary`

Comment: You need to use the sheet *code* name, not the sheet name. The code name can be found in the VB Editor, either from the Project Explorer or Properties Window.

Comment: Great! Glad to help.